# Installed GRUB in legacy mode, how do I reinstall it in EFI mode?

Tags: grub2, kali-linux, grub, uefi

I recently installed Kali on my Win 10 machine. Win 10 boots in EFI. I don't know how, but I somehow managed to install grub in legacy mode. Now I always have to switch between legacy and EFI in the BIOS depending if I want to boot into Win 10 or into Kali. Is there a way to reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition and get it all to work so that GRUB will start up Win 10 and Kali?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to boot Linux with EFI mode to get access to EFI variables and the ability to use `efibootmgr` so you can switch to grub. [This guide may be of some use](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/EFI_examples).

The procedure I would use would be as follows:

1. Install `efibootmgr` when booted into Linux.
2. Boot into an EFI-enabled Linux livecd **in EFI mode**. Any would do.
3. Ensure you are in EFI mode by checking for the existence of `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. If I'm not in EFI mode it's not present.
4. Choose a mount point for the main distribution. I'll use `/mnt/target` as an example.
5. I would run `mount /dev/<root partition> /mnt/target`, then `mount -t proc proc /mnt/target/proc`, `mount -t sysfs sysfs /mnt/target/sys`, `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/target/dev`, and `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/target/run`. I would also make sure to mount other partitions from my install if needed, including `/boot`, and also mount the EFI partition (usually the first one) to `/mnt/target/boot/efi` after creating that directory.
6. I now have my environment set up. `chroot /mnt/target`.
7. Run `grub2-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi` inside the chroot.
8. Run something like `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/<disk> -p Y -l \EFI\grub\bootx64.efi" -L "GRUB"` if grub2-install doesn't do that for you. You'll want to ensure the path to the bootx64.efi file is GRUB2's EFI file in `/boot/efi`.
9. Exit the chroot, unmount everything in reverse order you mounted, then reboot.
10. It should now boot into GRUB2 by default.

Comment: Untrue.  You can also get at the UEFI variables from Windows 10 or from the UEFI Shell.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 item 3 above was not about *accessing* the efivars but rather about *checking* that the host is booted in EFI mode

Comment: @MichaelShigorin   Item 8 above is about accessing UEFI variables.

Comment: *sigh* go access those with `efibootmgr` using win10, UEFI shell, any other atrocity, and let's not spam the discussion anymore before you're done with that.

Comment: I also had to do `mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`